# Should I update local storage every new event in a chat app?

Tags: messaging, sqlite, chat, local-storage

I am building a chat app using flutter and sqflite. In the chats screen we display a list of chats, each contain name and last message. Every time a user sends a message, should I update the last message column in the local storage? Or maybe when disposing the screen I update the last message? What is the best practice?

I store the message every time in a variable and then store it when before dispose.

Comment: The best practice is to think about the consequences of each decision and choose the one that best fits your requirements. That's how you learn the most and improve your skills. Disposing the screen is hard to control in a browser. If you have only a native app, maybe it's more of an option. Updating every time is simple. But you're not even saying what you would update and why it would matter. Maybe in your app it just doesn't matter. We can't tell.

Comment: See: [Why questions about "the correct way" are too broad](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/why-questions-about-the-correct-way-are-too-broad)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a number of problems to deal with which make it more than just a simple question of writing to local storage.

1. You need to be able to recover when local storage has been deleted
2. You need to ensure that local storage doesn't fill up
3. You need to take reasonable precautions with data for people using a public machine

Number one is probably the overriding technical issue. However you store the data locally you will need to be able to sync up with a list of messages from the server when the user reconnects with a potentially damaged or missing local list. (imagine they use two machines and the messages get split over both)

The simplest solution to this would be to simply download the last X messages and overwrite the local store on each new connection. But this begs the question of why have a local store at all.

If you have a requirement for local storage of messages then the sync up becomes more complicated, maybe have an index 1,2,3,4 for messages so that you can detect missing ones and request them from the server and only request new messages

Secondly, browser local storage is pretty limited, 5 MiB? so you could be hitting that pretty quickly, especially if you have rich text messages and definitely if you have images. So you need to evict old messages to make way for new ones. If you are on a mobile device you will have more room, but its definitely worth thinking about how many and how long you will store messages.

Again, if you can't store all the messages locally it calls into question the reasons for storing any of them locally.

Finally, you definitely don't want other people to read people's messages. and encrypting them locally in a browser on a shared machine is going to be tricky to do. The easy solution is just not to store them locally at all.

Edit -- just realising that maybe you mean "local storage" == sqlite database on mobile device with no server side storage at all. In which case although many of the point above still apply there is no cost to simply writing every time you hit send.

Comment: Or even every ten seconds if you made a change. So I can type a long message, get distracted, an hour later the app crashes, and when I restart it, the unsent message is still there.